# Kendo Grid: populating with data from ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm trying to populate a kendo grid with data retrieved via ajax. Here is the ajax:

```
    var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model));

            $(document).ready(function () {

                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Utilities/Report/Run",
                    data: JSON.stringify(model),
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    type: "POST",
                    success: function(result) {
                        var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                            data: result
                        });
                        alert(result);
                        $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").setDataSource(ds);
                    },
                    error: function(result) {
                        options.error(result);
                    }
                });

                $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                    toolbar: ["excel", "pdf"],
                    excel: {
                        fileName: "test"
                    },
                    pdf: {
                        fileName: "test"
                    },
                });
            });
```

At the `alert(result)` this is what the data looks like:

```
[
  {"TEST":"one"},
  {"TEST":"two"},
  {"TEST":"three"}
]
```

The ajax call appears to be working and the data looks good to me, but the kendo grid is not updating, it remains blank. I also do not get any error. I've tried placing the kendoGrid inside the ajax success function with the same result. I've tried using `transport` and `read` in the DataSource to retrieve the data but that kept giving me an error: `n.slice is not a function`. However, others seemed to think that was because there was no schema defined. Due to the kind of data I am retrieving, I cannot define this. The data retrieved from the server could have any column/field names, and any number of columns. It is not complex JSON however.

How do I get my grid to populate with this data?

Comment: Buddy, I already had that issue but I can't reproduce it neither remember the solution. But the little I recall is something about the object you pass to the dataSource, in your case `result` object. Make sure it is a javascript object and not string or something like (even noticing that you have added `contentType: "application/json"`). Perhaps if you try using it as `{ data: result }` and define your `schema.data: "data"` just to help kendo understando your data. This issue sucks and it happens since forever, I'm afaid they will never fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a new Datasource and mapped it to the existing one outside the success method. 
Can you try this one below :

```
  var newDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "/Utilities/Report/Run",
                dataType: "json",
                data: JSON.stringify(model),

                error: function (result) {
                    options.error(result);
                }
            }
        }
    });

   var d1 = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
   d1.dataSource.data([]);
   d1.setDataSource(newDataSource );
```

make changes as per your necessity if I have missed any . Kendo data binding is always confusing :D

Answer (score 0):

Kendo DataSource is very powerful. Ideally, you do not need to make a manual  Ajax call. Instead, DataSource can Ajax request data from URL by itself, if Grid needs data.

https://jsfiddle.net/6gxqsrzu/

```js
$(function() {
  var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    type: "odata",
    transport: {
      read: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Orders"
    },
    schema: {
      model: {
        fields: {
          OrderID: {
            type: "number"
          },
          Freight: {
            type: "number"
          },
          ShipName: {
            type: "string"
          },
          OrderDate: {
            type: "date"
          },
          ShipCity: {
            type: "string"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    serverPaging: true,
    pageSize: 5,
    serverSorting: true,
    sort: {
      field: 'OrderDate',
      dir: 'asc'
    }
  });

  $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: dataSource,
    sortable: true,
    pageable: true,
    columns: [{
        field: "OrderID",
        filterable: false
      },
      "Freight", {
        field: "OrderDate",
        title: "Order Date",
        format: "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}"
      }, {
        field: "ShipName",
        title: "Ship Name"
      }, {
        field: "ShipCity",
        title: "Ship City"
      }
    ]
  });
});
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.material.mobile.min.css" />

    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<div id="grid"></div>
```